# How to unlock mobile framerate beyond screen refresh rate in Unreal Engine? Can I get the actual CPU and GPU time during rendering?

Tags: mobile, unreal-engine5

I have tried several methods, such as setting FrameRateLock=true and bEnableDynamicMaxFPS=true, but they can only allow the mobile device to unlock up to the upper limit of the refresh rate of their screen. Is it possible to increase the frame rate of the game beyond the screen refresh rate through configuration? ? If it cannot be unlocked, is it possible to obtain the rendering time of the CPU and GPU during actual rendering (they are displayed correctly in Stat Unit)?

I tried using the method from this https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/SharingAndReleasing/Mobile/Rendering/MobileFramePacing/;

It seems that GGameThreadTime and GRenderThreadTime are the wrong display times, they are based on the frame rate time being limited